# OpenSSL non-blocking sockets SSL_Read() still blocks

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, openssl, winsock

I have a client/server program written in C++ for windows which I nearly done integrating OpenSSL into.

I do want to state that I have looked over all the other posts similar to my own, and I have not yet found the correct answer to my problem.  Most of the other exmaples are very close to the answer, but I cannot seem to produce the actual result.

For my test case I am simply passing a string of 7 characters from the client to the server using OpenSSL secure sockets every 5 seconds.  I am not sending any other information.  The original problem was that I was not using SSL_read correctly and I was not reading in the apparent extra data that was needed, and the SSL_read would stop responding and the client would lose connection.

After reading all of the other examples I got a couple steps further to accomplishing this, but I could never get the desired result.  I have attempted over 10 types of SSL_read implementations and I cannot get the code to be non-blocking while reading data.  I will post my latest implementation (not incredibly optimized):

```
int received = -1;
int tE = 0;

    if( tE != SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ && tE != SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE )
    {
        received = SSL_read(sSecureSocket.ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); 
        if( received == -1 )
        {
            tE = SSL_get_error( sSecureSocket.ssl, received );
            if( tE == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ )
            {
                int tReadWaiting = 1;
                while( tReadWaiting )
                {
                    tReadWaiting = 0;
                    fd_set rfd;
                    FD_ZERO(&rfd);
                    FD_SET(receiveSocket, &rfd);
                    timeval tv = { 0 };
                    select(receiveSocket+1, &rfd, 0, 0, &tv);
                    if (!FD_ISSET(receiveSocket, &rfd))
                    {
                        tReadWaiting = 1;
                    }
                }
                received = SSL_read(sSecureSocket.ssl, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); 
            }
        }
    }
```

This code does successfully extract the packet every time it is sent, however as you can see I must use the select() statement once the SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ/WRITE is triggered.  This approach was taken from another thread of this forum, say that you are supposed to read UNTIL the SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ/WRITER are called.  Also, I do use SSL_pending() but it always returns 0 in every case I have, never is it a non-zero number.

The program is written with non-blocking sockets with WSAASyncSelect calls to windows messages.  All of that works fine.

But what happens is the opposite of what I expect.  The code seems to always wait for data which is non existent.  I realize the the SSL sockets are meant to do handshakes at random times as well.  I am just trying to figure out why once I have received that the data from the server, why it seems that SSL_read seems to have data, or select() detects data needs to be be read in between the 5 second intervals in which I send my packet so that the select() loop blocks for the whole time.  Even once the packet is completely read, the next message is called back into the read function and the program itself can never leave this function to do any other processes.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've never been at my wit's end programming before, this is bringing me very close to it.

**UPDATE 1:**

This is the socket listening code:

```
ctx = sSecureSocket.InitServerCTX();        // initialize SSL 
    sSecureSocket.LoadCertificates(ctx, VGlobal::CURRWORKDIR + "\\openssl2\\" + "mycert.pem", VGlobal::CURRWORKDIR + "\\openssl2\\" + "mycert.pem"); // load certs 
    servSecureSocket = sSecureSocket.OpenListener(39245);    // create server socket
```

This is called when the socket is accepted on the server:

```
//Always connect as a secure socket first
struct sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
SSL *ssl;

receiveSocket = accept(servSecureSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);  // accept connection as usual 
printf("Connection: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
sSecureSocket.ssl = SSL_new(ctx);              // get new SSL state with context 
SSL_set_fd(sSecureSocket.ssl, receiveSocket);      // set connection socket to SSL state 
sSecureSocket.Servlet(sSecureSocket.ssl);         // service connection
```

These are the functions:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------
int SecureSocket::OpenListener(int port)
{   int sd;
struct sockaddr_in addr;

WSADATA wsadata;
int error = WSAStartup( 0x0202, &wsadata );

if( error )
    return false;

sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
//bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
if ( bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
{
    perror("can't bind port");
   // abort();
}
if ( listen(sd, 10) != 0 )
{
    perror("Can't configure listening port");
   // abort();
}
return sd;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
SSL_CTX* SecureSocket::InitServerCTX(void)
{   
SSL_METHOD *method;
SSL_CTX *ctx;

OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
SSL_load_error_strings();   /* load all error messages */
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());
if ( ctx == NULL )
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
}
return ctx;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
void SecureSocket::LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, CString CertFile, CString KeyFile)
{
/* set the local certificate from CertFile */
if ( SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
}
/* set the private key from KeyFile (may be the same as CertFile) */
if ( SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
}
/* verify private key */
if ( !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx) )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
}
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
void SecureSocket::ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{   X509 *cert;
char *line;

cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* Get certificates (if available) */
if ( cert != NULL )
{
    printf("Server certificates:\n");
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
    free(line);
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
    free(line);
    X509_free(cert);
}
else
    printf("No certificates.\n");
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
void SecureSocket::Servlet(SSL* ssl) /* Serve the connection -- threadable */
{
int acceptDone = SSL_accept(ssl);

//If this blocking this will be done immediately, if it is not we must loop until it is complete
while( acceptDone < 1 )
{
    acceptDone = SSL_accept(ssl);
}

ShowCerts(ssl);        /* get any certificates */
}
```

Comment: If you finish reading all of the data you are expecting, STOP READING. Like you said, there is no more data to read. That explains why `SSL_read()` reports `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` (a non-blocking read is not satisfyable without more data), and why `select()` times out (no new data is on the socket). BTW, you need to handle the case where `SSL_read()` reports `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` (yes, a write operation during a read operation! This happens during renegotiations). And you are not doing any error handling on `select()`, but you should so you can differentiate errors from timeouts.

Comment: And lastly, don't use a loop with a 0 ms timeout on `select()`. That is wasteful of CPU cycles. Your loop is waiting indefinitely until the socket is readable. You don't need a loop for that. Call `select()` once with an infinite timeout.  A better option is to call `select()` once with a decent timeout (say, 5 sec) without a loop, and if it times out then fail your read operation and move on.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for the tip on the select() statement, that makes a great deal more sense to add the timer and remove the loop.  This allowed me to see the (hopefully) true problem.  The server is receiving RD_READ calls which I assume are handshakes, they go in the SSL_read() but that returns SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ when there is nothing to read, so it goes into the select() statement and hangs until my "legitimate" packets are sent, the select ends, the packet is succesfully read, but the FD_READ was called again and once again, receives the WANT_READ and hangs in select() again.

Comment: FD_READ simply means the socket is readable, either because new data is ready to be read or because the other party has disconnected. If you call `SSL_read()` and it reports WANT_READ then there is not enough data to finish the current SSL message, so call `select()` and `SSL_read()` again, as many times as it takes, to finish the current SSL message until `SSL_read()` does not report WANT_READ anymore and you have collected as many decoded bytes as you were expecting (7 in your example).

Comment: @Remy okay, I actually understand that and it all worked, and I now have it "working" as it is passing packets back and forth to client/server every 5 seconds.  However, what I had to do was time out the select() statement with a very low timer (I am using 100ms right now).  I guess I needed to explain this in more detail...

Comment: @Remy When the client connects to the server, I also receive a FD_READ call that I did not send ( I do no SSL_write() ) so this is a connect protocol or a handshake done by OpenSSL.  When the SSL_read() calls on the server it fails with WANT_WRITE error, however there seems to actually be no data to be read, the data must have been extracted by an SSL layer when it was read, but I still receive the FD_READ call for it.  So it goes into the select() statement and locks the application because I am waiting for read data that never comes.  So I have to hack select() with a timeout to exit.

Comment: @Remy Debugging the client, the message does get send sent immeditately when the SSL_connect() call comes from the client.

Comment: `SSL_connect()` performs a handshake with `SSL_accept()`. That can trigger FD_READs. **DO NOT** call `SSL_read()` until `SSL_connect()` returns 1 indicating it has completed that handshake. If `SSL_connect()` reports WANT_READ or WANT_WRITE, call `select()` until the socket is ready and then call `SSL_connect()` again. If WANT_READ, ask `select()` for readability. If WANT_WRITE, ask `select()` for writability.

Comment: Whenever you get a WANT_READ, wait for the socket to become readable (`select()` or `FD_READ`) and then repeat the same SSL operation again.  Whenever you get a WANT_WRITE, wait for the socket to become writable (`select()`  or `FD_WRITE`) and then repeat the same SSL operation again.  OpenSSL handles the rest internally.

Comment: @Remy That all makes sense to me and I am trying to not call SSL_read() for those handshakes.  But the question is HOW do I detect that I am getting a handshake?  FD_READ seems to be called randomly for these as well throughout the program and I have no way of detecting if it a legit packet I sent, or a random handshake, so they all get called by SSL_read().

Comment: @Remy My current solution is this:  After an FD_READ is triggered, call `SSL_peek()` to read the data, if it returns an error then do not call `SSL_read()`.  This seems to work but seems dirty.  Because what if a legitimate WANT_READ or WANT_WRITE call occurs?  I could have just dropped a legitimate packet.

Comment: UPDATE: What I am now doing is a `select()` statement before my first `SSL_read()` call with a timeout of 0 to check if it returns something to actually read.  So the FD_READ call is made, then the select() checks again if this is true, if it false, don't call `SSL_read()`  I hope there is no problems with this method.

Comment: Your app needs to keep track of what it is doing with the socket. When it gets an `FD_READ`, if it is not expecting inbound **application** data yet then DO NOT call `SSL_read()` yet. If it is in the middle of performing a handshake instead, call `SSL_connect()` (if connecting) or `SSL_accept()` (if accepting). Why is that so hard to understand? OpenSSL uses a state machine, but you are obviously not following the rules of that state machine. It sounds like your `FD_READ` handler is completely oblivious to what the rest of your code is doing to trigger the `FD_READ`s, and that is not good.

Comment: @Remy First of all I thank you for sticking with me on this.  Short answer to this, I was calling SSL_accept() in a blocking loop in the same function as accepting the socket to listen for the `SSL_connect()` call.  THEN FD_READ was triggered.  But even if I move the `SSL_accept()` loop to begin checking after the FD_READ call.  Its just the same result, I accept, and exit out of FD_READ.

Comment: @Remy When I am debugging the code, and I am hitting breakpoints, sometimes I get these "already read" packets again through FD_READ, which are probably another handshake of some sort, if I continue to "drop" these packets on the FD_READ call, I get no errors, no problems, and I am still successfully sending my actual application packets back and forth successfully.  So yes, SSL must be processing packets somewhere else before the FD_READ call is made, then calling FD_READ with no more read data left in the socket.

Comment: @Remy I have posted all the server code I use to listen, and accept in **UPDATE 1**  Its just simple code from another example.  How it is overriding FD_READ I have no idea.