# How to retrieve fd from BIO to use with select()?

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm trying to implement non-blocking SSL sockets by setting BIO to non-blocking, then passing the read (`SSL_get_rbio`) and write (`SSL_get_wbio`) to a `select()` statement.

However, I'm unsure as too how to pass these, as clearly the select statement only take `fd_set` types?

Code:

```
BIO *sslbio;
sslbio=BIO_new_socket(sock,BIO_NOCLOSE);
long block_status=1;
long nonb=BIO_set_nbio(sslbio,block_status);
BIO *r = SSL_get_rbio(ssl); 
BIO *w = SSL_get_wbio(ssl);
SSL_set_bio(ssl,r,w);

struct timeval tv, tvRestore;
tv.tv_sec=10;
tv.tv_usec=0;
tvRestore=tv;

if(SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0)
{
   std::cout<<"SSL_accept ERROR"<<std::endl;
}
else
{
   int select_int=select(client + 1,r,w,NULL,&tvRestore);
}
```

The error is:

```
"cannot convert ‘BIO* {aka bio_st*}’ to ‘fd_set*’ for argument ‘2’
  to ‘int select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timeval*)"
```

Any ideas on how I can connect these up?

Comment: The [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) function used file descriptor sets. To populate them you need the actual file descriptors (small integers, as created by the `socket` call for example). There are thousands of tutorials on how to use [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html). And you need to learn how to extract the socket file descriptor from the `BIO` structures.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks, could you explain roughly how I can get these file descriptors?

Comment: I don't know anything about the OpenSSL library and the `BIO` structure. But a very quick search (which you should be able to do yourself) I found out about something called [`BIO_get_fd`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_get_fd).

Comment: By the way, one suggestion about doing this: Don't. It's very difficult to get right and very easy to get wrong. Instead, use BIO pairs and don't let the BIO touch the socket at all.

Comment: `cd` into you OpenSSL source code. And then issue the following from your `<openssl source>` directory: ` grep -IR select apps/`. You will get about 25 hits. They show you how the OpenSSL library uses `select()` in its apps/sub-commands, like `ocsp` (`openssl ocsp`), `s_client` (`openssl s_client`) and `s_server` (`openssl s_server`).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Before you get too many upvotes by folks who don't know... `select()` is recommended when using non-blocking BIOs. Otherwise, `SSL_Read` does not work as expected. Its the reason utilities like `ocsp` do it. Also see questions like [OpenSSL non-blocking sockets SSL_Read() still blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16381628).

Comment: @jww If you're going to do the `select`, you can do the `read` (or `write`) as well. It makes the design simpler and leaves fewer ways you can get things wrong. It's simpler not to split responsibility for the socket. OpenSSL supports BIO pairs for this purpose.